# Installing an Intermediate/chain certificate using Java Key Tool

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7, ssl-certificate, jks

I have a JKS file made for Confluence that already contains my private and public key.
It works fine with most browser albeit one small issue.
On sslshopper I get the following message:

> The certificate is not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to
>   install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root
>   certificate.

I got the CA chain + Root from Comodo, read through and attempted the following:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore fecru.jks -storepass SECRET -trustcacerts -alias chain -file cachain.bundle
```

Even though the cert was successfully added the to key store I still get the same results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your chain bundle file likely has multiple certificates in it. IIRC, `keytool` can't deal with bundles, only single certificates, so it probably imported the first certificate in the bundle and ignored the rest. What does `keytool -list -v -keystore [yourkeystore]` show you?

Comment: I also tried added them all seperately. same results. I have 4 aliases right now. 1 for the cert itself, 1 for root, and 2 more for intermidiate.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what I have in my "Java TLS with Keystores" cheat-sheet, which I need to refer to all the time because, for some reason, if you don't do it perfectly, nothing seems to work.

1. Generate a server key (and self-signed certificate)

   `$ keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keysize 4096`**`-alias ${HOSTNAME}`**`-keystore ${HOSTNAME}.jks`
2. Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)

   `$ keytool -certreq -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keystore ${HOSTNAME}.jks`
3. Get your CSR signed by a Certificate Authority (CA)
4. Import the certificates back into your keystore, starting with the CA's root certificate and going down the chain back to your server's certificate

   `$ keytool -import -alias [Authority.CA] -trustcacerts -file [authority's CA cert] -keystore ${HOSTNAME}.jks`

   `$ keytool -import -alias [Authority.intermediate] -trustcacerts -file [authority's intermediate cert] -keystore ${HOSTNAME}.jks`

   `$ keytool -import`**`-alias ${HOSTNAME}`**`-file ${HOSTNAME}.crt -keystore ${HOSTNAME}.jks`

I always make a backup copy of the keystore after I generate my server's key just in case I break something.

A few things are *critically* important:

1. Remember to use the same `alias` in steps 1 and 4c (importing your server's signed certificate) above
2. Remember to set the `keyAlias` attribute in Tomcat's `<Connector>` to the same value you have used for your server's certificate (again, the same value as steps 1 and 4c above)

I highly recommend using [Qualys's SSLTest](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) tool to test your site. It is the most comprehensive testing tool I know of, and it's not trying to sell you anything.