# Error: unable to verify the first certificate - Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

I have written a restful API project which is developed using spring boot and I am using the embedded tomcat and running a jar on a linux server.

The APIs are live at:

```
  https://api.arevogroup.com:8089/api/regions
```

and I can see the verified and correct SSL as well as in the given screenshot. [image]

**but I am getting an this exception in the postman when I call these apis.**
[image]

These APIs are consumed by a Xamrin based app which seems to work all good when consumed using iPhone but gives this same exception when the APIs are accessed via android.

I guess, the way I have generated the ssl certificate has some issues.

I have used a pfx file and my SSL config in properties file looks like this:

```
###SSL Key Info
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store-password=PASSWORD
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl_pfx.pfx
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
```

1. I have 2 questions, if disable the ssl verification, would the communication still be encrypted or not? (man in the middle attack is still possible but the info will still be encrypted, right?).
2. If not, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store-password=PASSWORD
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

Used the jks file instead of pfx and it worked all good. Thought to share with others too.

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable the verification of the **server** certificate. No browser will allow you to do it, except on an exceptional basis (the user must confirm the exception). If the client disables the verification, than the communication will be encrypted (i.e. no passive attack will be possible).

The errors you see are cause by a misconfiguration of your server.
Your certificate chain contains just the certificate for your server and lacks the intermediate certificate `CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2`. You need to download it from [Go Daddy](https://certs.godaddy.com/repository) (it is the one named `gdig2.crt.pem`) and add it to your keystore.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41416050/11748454) on how to do it.

Some browsers cache intermediate certificates and are able to verify your site even if one certificate is missing. However you should not rely on it.